# Visual Studio (with Team Foundation Server) - How to get back to "Resolve" screen?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005

I started resolving conflicts in a merge and then had to quit to set something up. Now I don't see any way to get back to the stupid conflict resolution window. If I try to merge again it just gives me a bunch of warnings about the pending merge I already have? This is in Visual Studio 2005.

Comment: hi there did you get an answer?

Answer (score 0):

The merge will have been rolled back if you canceled out of it. Can you run tf merge from a visual studio command line?